# Create a Dll of a Login Form project is fine?

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, nuget

**Context:** I am on a team, we develop different applications in `C# Winforms`, almost all applications need a `Login form`; We used to recreate or copy paste the most recent `Login form` every time we started new app development so I made a version that can be deployed to all apps without having to do that. But now we are having trouble figuring out how we can avoid copying and pasting the project over and over again.

Referencing the .exe seems to work, but we still have to copy and paste the .exe on each computer where we develop an application. I am learning about nuget to load our `DLLs`, but I don't think it is a good idea to convert the `Login form` into a `DLL` just to use it in all projects, also the login project is using the other `DLLs` that we are using constantly on every project, I think it's kind of redundant.

**Final Question:** Is it ok to convert the `Login Form` to a `DLL` and upload it to Nuget, or is there another way to share the same project?

Comment: "but I don't think it is a good idea to convert the Login form into a DLL just to use it in all projects" - why not? Where do you think the `Form` base class comes from? You also don't need to bother with NuGet if you don't want to.

Comment: It's a good idea to create reusable components where you can use it in almost every project. Just make it resilient enough..

Comment: your depenency 'tree' isn't clear "also the login project is using the other DLLs that we are using constantly on every project" - so the login form refereneces the rest of the application? if thats the case then you are going to struggle packaging it into a stand alone dll, since you will need to change the references everytime to reference your new application. Add some clarity and we should be able to help. Apart from my previous point, there should be no issue in making this a dll and optionally using nuget, thats pretty much why they exist

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, i decided to reduce the dependencies in the `Login Form` project and convert it to a `Dll` in a category like `"Components"`. You're right, i was just overthinking the situation, `DLLs` are for that purpose and its nothing bad in convert an application into a `DLL` even more when you're going to reuse that app in diferents projects.
I will do the same with a `Calculator`. Thanks again for all your answers :)